# Python changing arrays (numpy) using the map command

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, plot, scatter

I imported data from a file in order to make a scatter plot. The data from the csv file is not exactly what I will plot, as for the second col I want the sum of the prior entries in the col to be my y axis.

I am having trouble converting from an array to sum the data using the map command. As i am receving the error:

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy

x,y = numpy.loadtxt ('LAX_booths_data_set_1.csv',
                  unpack = True,
                  delimiter = ',')
x2,y2 = numpy.loadtxt ('LAX_booths_data_set_2.csv',
                  unpack = True,
                  delimiter = ',')


newy = map(sum, y)
newy2 = map(sum, y2)


pyplot.plot(x,newy)
pyplot.plot(x2,newy2)

pyplot.title('Comparing Different Booth Schedules')
pyplot.ylabel('Number of Booths (Total)')
pyplot.xlabel('Time (Minutes)')

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Did you print out `y` and/or `y2` to see how they differed from what you expected?  (Aside: there's no need to use `map` here, because `numpy` has a simpler and faster `sum` method, but might as well start from where you are.)  [I'm assuming here that it's the `map` which is causing the problem -- you didn't post the full traceback.]

Comment: yes an example of the content of x and y would be helpful

Comment: full traceback : File "C:\Users\fkrueg1\Dropbox\forest_python_test\Graphnew.py", line 12, in <module>
    newy = map(sum, y)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: x is [   30.   100.   200.   400.   600.   900.  1200.  1400.  1450.]
y is [ 10.  -5.  20.  -5.  50. -20.  30. -20.  20.]

Comment: and you want the newy to be the cumulative sum of y ? [10., 5., 25., 20. ... ]

Comment: i want [10, 5, 25, 20,...], so prior entry + next entry excluding the first one, which stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So map apply the function to all elements of the array independently, and i think that you want to use numpy.cumsum

```
newy = numpy.cumsum(y)
```